# HTML, JQuery, JavaScript - How to fill input file on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **fill input file on load How, please help me**
>
> some code not work :

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="fup" value="" />
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('fup').value = "C:/AiOLog.txt";
    }
</script>
```

[Image After code , nothing changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAhdk.png)

Comment: Not possible with the type of file. Use another element to display the filename i.e. <div id='fupName'></div> then use document.getElementById('fupName').innerHTML = 'ddddd'. BTW the drive letter is not required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: This is not possible. If this was possible every web site that you visit would be able to access your local files and upload them to a web server.

Comment: not work @jeff .

Comment: i need to solve this , plz help me anyone

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a value to an `input[type=file]` element, because its very dangerous for a user. If the browser allow to do this then everyone will be able to get the files from the system of the user of a website, which is totally irrelevant for a user's privacy.

Comment: It is possible to set the value of an input[type=file] using the contents of an other input[type=file] but it is not possible to set the value of an  input[type=file] using a local file.

Comment: No, it;s not possible in any way to manipulate a `input[type=file]` data. You should you any other logic for the work you are trying to do

Comment: Shridhar you are right. I am sorry for the inaccurate comment.